# Can Dual link DVI be broken while single link still works?

Tags: display, amd-radeon, dvi

I have a 144hz BenQ monitor with dual link DVI input. It was working fine, but then I updated my Radeon drivers and being in a rush I just clicked "apply changes" when it popped up with suggestions to change something. The screen instantly went static and has been that since. When I connect a dual link DVI cable to it I get nothing but static or "no cable connected" and when I use the monitor on another computer with another dual link DVI cable I still get the same issue.

I've used display driver uninstaller and completely removed everything connected to AMD from the PC and reinstalled the drivers for the GPU but I still get the same issue.

If I use a single link DVI cable then the monitor works fine. Can the dual part of the input be broken while the single part still works?

Comment: Consider the possibility that something unrelated broke the dual link cable and/or monitor connecters, and that this happening at the same time as you upgraded the drivers is coincidence. (You can e.g. test if it's the cable by borrowing a working cable from someone else).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did try with another dual link dvi cable without any difference.

Comment: Then "doesn't work with another dual-link cable on another computer" suggests "connector or receiver circuit for the second link on the monitor is broken". I can't think of an easy way to verify this.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was thinking. But I didn't know if only one part of it could break and leave the other part intact.

Comment: There are several ways how one port could break and leave the other port intact, e.g. (1) pin or solder point belonging to one port broke in the connector, (2) receiver chip for one port broke, etc.